# ansible is blocked waiting for unresponsive services using service module

Tags: asynchronous, service, state, ansible

I have the following playbook,
I tested and all tasks are working fine except when ansible trying to stop an unresponsive service in the host. It keep wainting for a long long time and never get a response from server ( no timeout, no failed, no nothing ).

In this case is not useful for me async and poll or "fire and forget" method, I have try to do Stop first before to do a kill -9.

```
- hosts: '{{ hostname }}'

  become: yes

  vars_prompt:
       hostname: "Enter hostname"


  tasks:
  - name: Stop 
    service: name=some_service state=stopped pattern=some_pattern 
    register: stop_disabled_services
    ignore_errors: yes

  - name: Stop output
    debug: msg="{{ stop_disabled_services }}"

  - name: Killing process
    shell: kill -9 $(cat /opt/day/cq5/publish/crx-quickstart/conf/cq.pid) 
    register: output
    when: "stop_disabled_services | failed"

  - name: Killing output
    debug: msg="{{ output.stdout }}"
    when: "output | failed"

  - name: start
    service: name=some_service state=started
    register: start_disabled_services

  - name: Result
    debug: msg="WARNING Escalated this incident "
    when: "start_disabled_services | failed"

  - name: Result
    debug: msg="Start up complete successfully"
    when: "start_disabled_services | success"
```

You have idea how can i trobleshoot it ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it.
I used async method and with command: sleep 300 in the next task. So the playbook wait 300 seconds, if didn't stop then playbook continues and using kill -9.
Teporal solution but is working.

Comment: Is this a service you've written yourself? Have you considered putting the wait followed by a kill -9 in the stop part of the init script for the service? That takes this clutter out of the Ansible and puts it into a better place.

Comment: Thanks for answering , No is not wrote by me . The problem is that the playbook runs into jumphost and reach the servers from this one, I should modify a lot of server to do that .